# How to enable PwdAccountLockedTime in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I wanna set `PwdAccountLockedTime` attribute for `000001010000Z` value and deactivate user account. I know how this works, but I have problems with enabling `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute. At first, I just added `ppolicy` schema to my OpenLDAP, but now I'm completely lost. After some studying of OpenLDAP I found ppolicy is not a schema but an overlay, but this is really confusing for me, how can I add it? How can I work with the `PwdAccountLockedTime` attribute?

I'm using CentOS 7.3 and OpenLDAP in version 2.4.40 with  slapd.d configuration (not slapd.conf file). Thanks all for your help

Comment: It seems a space is missing between the OID and "SINGLE-VALUE". What happens if you put an extra space to the beginning of the last line?

Comment: Hm, I added some spaces to definition of this attribute and now I'm getting again error 80, but with  `additional info: olcAttributeTypes: "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.17" is operational`

Comment: If you load the original ppolicy schema, does this attribute appear in the cn=config database?

Comment: yes, it was there, but I don't know if I didn't something wrong, because when I removed some schema, I just removed that schema file from cn=config, I didn't use any ldap* command